# How can I integrate such layout with other layouts in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

[I want to ad this type of layout inside a linear or relative layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBfGy.png)

Comment: What you want a horizontal scroll bar inside a relative layout?

Comment: @AdamForbis bro you got it ,

Comment: Now do you just want to be able to scroll horizontally, or do you want that exact bar?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

Add horizontal scroll bar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100dip"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/hsv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:measureAllChildren="false"
    android:scrollbars="none" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/innerLay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

           //Your Code

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```